# Data Warehouse Hierarchical Events

Tags: design-patterns, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I need to model an event tracking system, items tracked are hierarchical (it's a relatively complex hierarchy, but I'll simplify it for this post). Progress is tracked at the lowest level, and then when all of the children reach a given state the parent is marked as completed.

It's not education, but this is a good way to illustrate the point, let's assume we have two levels:

- Class
- Module

A student takes a class that is constructed of many modules, so when all modules are completed the class is completed (following a test), and the student receives a certificate. Easy.

Some of the questions that users might want to ask include:

- Which students have started, but not finished a class
- Which students have *x* modules incomplete within a class
- How many students are more than 50% of a way to completing a class
- How long does it take (on average) to complete a course
- What is the completion rate of a course / module.
- Which students have achieved certificate x (following an exam)

There are some attributes that only exist at different levels of the learning hierarchy... but not very many. For example completed courses yield a certificate, which doesn't really exist at a module level, so this needs to be held against that record.

So we know the following:

1. 'things' need to be tracked at a module, and a class level, so we know we need a fact table for each grain.
2. these levels are hierarchical, so we know they need a relationship between them.
3. events kind of roll-up, but not in the way numeric measures can roll up

So at present, I kind of have this arrangement in my mind...

[image: Fig1]

The thought process here is that modules and classes are separate entities and need to be different dimensions in order to correctly describe the contents of the fact tables that reside at differing grains. I've not 100% thought through the relationship between the two, but it does exist in some capacity because the classes roll up into one another... so this is basically descendant tables similar to AdventureWorks Product > ProductSubCategory > ProductCategory, i don't *think* it can be maintained as a single table due to the need for fact tables of a different grain??

The other mechanism I have thought about, which now I type this out is potentially more flexible (i will think, and qualify this with an edit later) is maybe this...

[image: Fig2]

I suppose it would also be possible to pop-out the parent-child to more of an "adjacency list" style design, but I'm not sure at this point if that would be more, or less work to maintain...?

Something I have just thought about while writing this up though, is what happens if a module needs to be part of multiple classes... perhaps an adjacency list would be more suitable at that point? It's starting to turn into more of a "network" than hierarchy at this point though...

Comment: What questions are you trying to answer with your module tracking? What questions are you trying to answer with your class tracking? Is there information that exists only at the class level and doesn't exist at the module level?

Comment: good questions, i will amend the original query

Comment: I like the first approach because it's easier for the presentation layer to work with (SSAS, PowerBI, QuickView etc will love the simpler structure).  I'd be tempted to add ClassKey to F_ModuleTracking.  The direct, explicit, relationship makes [drilling acorss](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/04/the-soul-of-the-data-warehouse-part-two-drilling-across/) much easier.

Comment: I will do the ClassKey on F_ModuleTracking, good call. Also, because there are other parts of the hierarchy that have multi-level relationships I am strongly considering just decorating each fact table with individually maintained dimension tables. The hierarchy we actually have is actually more like Module > Class > Class-Set > Program > Degree and it is possible for classes to link straight to the top level, so the simpler the better perhaps. Ty!

Comment: decided to create accumulating snapshot fact for each "level" in the Module to Degree hierarchy in the end (mostly due to the ultra complex relationships between modules and classes [and other levels]) and assign all known levels of dimensionality in each fact as you suggest @destination-data.. this will allow the most flexibility in answering required questions although, however, my use case currently consists of "allow me to analyse course completion rates" ;)